# is logback losing messages upon configuration reload?

Tags: logback

I am trying to figure out whether logback is potentially losing messages.
Quoting from the log4j2 page:
"Like Logback, Log4j 2 can automatically reload its configuration upon modification. Unlike Logback, it will do so without losing log events while reconfiguration is taking place"

So, can anyone comment on logback losing log events? Does it really happen? 
(I have seen that event loss might occur using Async appenders, but can be solved using setting discardingThreshold 0, but the statement on log4j2 is talking about configuration reload)
I am trying to understand whether log4j2 is really more reliable, or shall we just use logback...

Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your setup "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception, post the line it occurred on and the exception details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Answer (score 2):

When logback is reconfigured it removes all the appender references and level settings from the loggers. It then reads the new configuration and applies them to the loggers. While this is happening logging is still continuing.

Log4j 2 separates the loggers from their configuration. Once a new configuration is created the loggers are pointed at the LoggerConfig of the new configuration. So for a brief time you will have some loggers pointing at the old configuration and some pointing at the new one, but they will never be unconfigured.

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently investigating this very question and, looking at the code, it indeed seems that log messages can be lost during reconfiguration. The following code is called by ReconfigureOnChangeFilter's ReconfiguringThread:

```
private void performXMLConfiguration(LoggerContext lc) {
  JoranConfigurator jc = new JoranConfigurator();
  jc.setContext(context);
  StatusUtil statusUtil = new StatusUtil(context);
  List<SaxEvent> eventList = jc.recallSafeConfiguration();
  URL mainURL = ConfigurationWatchListUtil.getMainWatchURL(context);
  lc.reset();
  long threshold = System.currentTimeMillis();
  try {
    jc.doConfigure(mainConfigurationURL);
    if (statusUtil.hasXMLParsingErrors(threshold)) {
      fallbackConfiguration(lc, eventList, mainURL);
    }
  } catch (JoranException e) {
    fallbackConfiguration(lc, eventList, mainURL);
  }
}
```

In lc.reset(), all appenders are removed (along with other configuration attributes), then the logger context is reconfigured. There is no apparent synchronization going on.

A quick test verified that messages are lost during reconfiguration.